# Image path is not working after removing public from URL in laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

My images are working fine in anchor text. but when I remove public from URL (by putting .htaccess in root directory) Image path is not working.

```
<a href="new_profile.php" class="thumbnail">
  <img src="admin_images/noti.png" alt="..."><strong>Profile</strong>
</a>
```

This admin_images folder is in Public folder.

Comment: You tried with a slash? `<img src="/admin_images/noti.png" alt="..."><strong>Profile</strong>`

Comment: Try <img src="{{ url('admin_images/noti.png') }}" alt="..."><strong>Profile</strong>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[url()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-url) generates an absolute URL to the given path and [asset()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-asset) generates a URL to an application asset.

Here the code:

> `<img src="{{asset('admin_images/noti.png')}}"
>   alt="..."><strong>Profile</strong>`

-will do the job. Otherwise you will have an external error(maybe from your .htaccess).

The **asset** function generates a URL for an asset using the current scheme of the request

Comment: `<img src="/admin_images/noti.png" alt="..."><strong>Profile</strong>` will show if there is an image available in **/public/admin_images/noti.png** and you are accessing the application's root page(path) only!

Comment: <img src="{{asset('public/admin_images/setting-icon.png')}}" alt="..."><strong>Setting</strong>  this is working